Show Hide Post Information based on term clicked by user
let me explain my requirements. I have WordPress website and I have created a custom post type reviews. Single post have acf fields which I want to show up depending upon the the term user clicks on taxonomy archive page. So under custom post type review I have taxonomy with slug vendor category and under this taxonomy I have terms with business-banking, business-line-of-credit and business-loans. Now what I want is that if user click on business banking term on archive page acf field to be shown is banking field and if user click on business-line-of-credit then acf field to be shown is line_of_credit  and so on . Also one post is assigned to multiple terms so information showed on single post depend upon the clicked term.
is this something possible if yes then how can we achieve this.

This is possible and it can be achieved but you're not really asking a question that we can provide an answer for.  What you're asking is for the work to be done for you.  If you posted your output code so that we could see how you were bringing in the fields and where we could reference the terms, etc. then maybe someone could give you an actual answer beyond "Yes, it can be done."

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
